# HTTPS not working after adding it to my EBS throught ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I created, validated and issued an ACM certificate.
Attached it to my Load balancer
Created rules to accept https connections on my security groups.

I get a connection refused error.

This is how my load balancer is configured:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcpRd.jpg

I checked the post below: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248771&tstart=0

But my Load balancer seems to be configured correctly. (According to the image above). And I am getting a connection refused instead of a timeout.

Am I missing any configs?

Important: I bought the domain outside amazon, I used route 53 to get the IPs to put on my domain provider. Maybe those DNS are pointing to EC2 instead of the load balancer? How can I confirm that, or do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my issue by redirecting the A entries on route 53 to the loadbalancer instead my elastic IP associated to my ec2 instance.